# Delete key does not work in Date Item (Smart GWT)

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, smartgwt

We had an issue with Date Item (using masking) in Smart GWT, where i am not able to delete the date item selected.
When I tried to delete the selected value (using delete button) in Date Item component only the first digit gets deleted and the cursor does not move to the second digit. This causes a lot of inconvenience to the end users.

I can see this issue exist in the smart gwt showcase (with masking enabled). 
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_masking

Please let me know if there is any fix .

Please help me.

Comment: consider posting it in the official smartgwt forum: http://forums.smartclient.com/

Answer (score 0):

It might be a work around but I've solved this problem by actually moving the caret once the user presses the delete key. You can use this to do that:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-release/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextItem.html#setSelectionRange%28int,%20int%29